Highcharter line chart is showing one category x axis label not correctly
Using this code I am trying to select one category out of three using selectInput but in the line chart I am not able to see the x axis category with full name as it is showing only 'C' rather than showing Category 1/Category 2/Category 3.
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("categories", "Select Categories:", 
              choices = c("Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3"),
              selected = c("Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3"),
              multiple = TRUE),  # Allow multiple selection
    highchartOutput("lineChart")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$lineChart <- renderHighchart({
   # Example data
   categories <- c("Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3")
    values <- c(5, 3, 8)  # Corresponding values for categories

    # Filter data based on selected categories
  selected_categories <- input$categories
     selected_values <- values[categories %in% selected_categories]

     # Create a data frame for plotting
     plot_data <- data.frame(Category = selected_categories, Value =      selected_values)

     # Ensure that the x-axis categories are set correctly
     highchart() %>%
       hc_chart(type = "line") %>%
       hc_title(text = "Line Chart Example") %>%
       hc_xAxis(categories = plot_data$Category,  # Use the filtered categories
                 title = list(text = "Categories"),
                 labels = list(rotation = -45, align = "right")) %>%  # Rotate      labels for better visibility
       hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Values")) %>%
       hc_add_series(name = "Sample Data", data = plot_data$Value)
   })
 }

 shinyApp(ui, server)


Your code displays fine (x-axis labels fully visible) on my machine. You might try increasing the height of your display or setting plot height e.g. through highchart(height = ...) to avoid clipping.

This is a known issue and the question is a duplicate to this one. See also jbkunst/highcharter#173, #155, #71 or #65 for further details.

This question is similar to: Highcharts X axis categories name gets only shows 1 character. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
